# Realm.IO - Can JSON array be parsed using createOrUpdateAllFromJson?

Tags: android, json, realm

Inside **Doctor** class, I have RealmList - **specializationList**.

```
public class Doctor extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String doctorId;
    private FullName fullName;
    private Age age;
    private String organizationId;
    private Position position;
    private String category;
    private String loyalty;
    private RealmList<Specialization> specializationList;
    private Contacts contacts;
    private String key;
....
```

**Specialization** class

```
public class Specialization extends RealmObject{

    private String specializationName;
...
```

Doctors JSON:

```
[
  {
    "doctorId": "7d8e72d7-809b-4273-9a3f-fa21718dee7f",
    "doctorFullName": {
      "firstName": "FirstName0",
      "lastName": "LastName0",
      "middleName": "MiddleName0"
    },
    "doctorPosition": {
      "positionName": "PositionName0",
      "department": "Department0"
    },
    "organizationId": "7cfaf5c0-127a-4cfc-b73b-52a35fd02ffd",
    "specializations": [
      {
        "specializationName": "Specialization name 3"
      },
      {
        "specializationName": "Specialization name 2"
      },
      {
        "specializationName": "Specialization name 1"
      }
    ],
    "key": "firstname0 middlename0 lastname0"
  }
]
```

Parsing JSON using **createOrUpdateAllFromJson** method:

```
realm.createOrUpdateAllFromJson(Doctor.class, json);
```

What I am trying to do is getting RealmList from **doctor** object:

```
RealmList<Specialization> specializationList = doctor.getSpecializationList();
```

But specializationList's size is 0.

**Realm documentation:**
Some JSON APIs will return arrays of **primitive** types like integers or Strings, which Realm doesn’t support yet.

Can JSON array(specializations) be parsed using createOrUpdateAllFromJson?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Realm should be able to parse that, but it looks like your naming is not right. Your Doctor class calls it `specializationList` but in your JSON it is `specializations`.

If you change your Doctor class to the following it should work:

```
public class Doctor extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String doctorId;
    private FullName fullName;
    private Age age;
    private String organizationId;
    private Position position;
    private String category;
    private String loyalty;
    private RealmList<Specialization> specializations;
    private Contacts contacts;
    private String key;
....
```

Comment: is there any solution if the JSON format is as follows:
   [
  {
    "doctorId": "7d8e72d7-809b-4273-9a3f-fa21718dee7f",
    "specializations": [
     "Specialization name 3"
     ,
    "Specialization name 2"
     ,
     "Specialization name 1"
    ],
    "key": "firstname0 middlename0 lastname0"
  }
]
I have an API response which JSON similar to as mentioned above. Any help would be greatly apreciated,